# Couldn't run my WinForm app when COR_ENABLE_PROFILING set

Tags: .net, winforms, registry, clsid

I couldn't run my .NET Framework Winform App when COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 1

If I delete COR_ENABLE_PROFILING from Registry Editor, it works fine.

Do you have any idea to run my app while COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 1?

Here is the error

```
.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - Loading profiler failed. COR_ENABLE_PROFILING was set properly, but COR_PROFILER was not. COR_PROFILER must be set to the CLSID of the profiler to load.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of my obfuscation tool's configuration. I disabled the debugging protection.